# LARAVEL: How to compile app.sass into app.css

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, npm, sass

**UPDATE** Running on Laravel 5.4.30 on Windows 10

**UPDATE:** Leaving the files as .scss works perfectly fine, but I do NOT want to use this in my project. I want to use indented sass, or .sass

Okay, so I have committed to hours upon hours of research before I decided to ask this question on here.
Simply put, how do I compile:

`resources/assets/sass/app.sass` into `public/css/app.css` in Laravel?

I've tried using Laravel Elixir.. total fail..

I've tried

`mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.sass', false, { indentedSyntax: true }, 'public/css');`

in `webpack.mix.js`

Notice the `{ indentedSyntax: true }`, this also didn't work.

I've installed the `node-sass` and `gulp` node modules.. still no success.

Here is my `_custom.sass` file found in the same directory as `app.sass`

```
// Fonts
// @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600")

// Variables
@import "variables"

// Bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap"

.flex-center
  display: none
```

`.flex-center` is the class in Laravel included in `welcome.blade.php`, I used this as a test and set display to none.

In my `app.sass` file, I just have:

```
@import "custom"
```

Do note that I changed `_variables.scss` to `_variables.sass`, so it isn't proper .sass syntax (but of course nothing is compiling anyway, so it's not like it matters)

I've tried the sass-loader, gulp-sass, compass-sass, nothing has worked.

There has GOT to be an easier way (or even a way at all) to use `.sass` in Laravel and have it compile to `app.css`!

I have a feeling it all has to do with my `webpack.mix.js` file, but there is very little documentation of the parameter setup to have it compile to `app.css`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've seen there are a number of people with this problem, thanks!

Comment: Is it on laravel 5.4?

Comment: @HimanshuBhandari yes it is indeed, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Simple fix.. clone or download lavarel's repo @ https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Though I've updated `package.json`, `webpack.mix.js`, etc., there must still be some extra files or code in the current/most-updated version.

After you download the repo, run `npm install` to be sure you have all necessary node_modules and don't run into any errors.

After `npm install`, you can successfully run `npm run dev` and compile any assets *including indented sass!*

Answer (score 10):

Though you have explained very well but I am still not getting where you stuck, anyway let me give it a try.

from laravel docs :

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.sass', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/admin.sass', 'public/css/admin');
```

after that :

```
// Run all Mix tasks...

npm run dev

// Run all Mix tasks and minify output...

npm run production
```

After that you can include the `.css` file generated in `public/css` in your `.blade` files through :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">
```

*If you are using Laravel 5.4 Elixer won't work.*

let me know if it is not what you want.

Comment: I'm trying this on a FRESH laravel project right now. The ONLY change I've made is adding: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}"> to welcome.blade.php, however I am getting an error. 2/2) ErrorException
The Mix manifest does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\app\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Comment: Please remove everything from app.scss and put only a single class to test if mix is working fine("npm run dev"). If it works fine than include it in app.blade.php

Comment: Okay I'll try that now. I'm completely removing node and npm and reinstalling because I've been getting a lot of errors using npm lately.

Comment: Had the same problem after running `npm install` finding that my `app.scss` file is empty.  I thought it would have some pre-compiled css in there.  But it turns out you can import bootstrap ect and create your own classes, therefore having much more control of your templates.  After adding my own classes and gridlayouts I find the laravel template system much more likeable.